# Allow PHP in Contact Form 7 editor

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a form to be able to get dynamic date values from php

My current form looks like the following:

```
[radio date default:1 "1" "2017-11-16" "2017-11-17" "2017-11-18" "2017-11-20" "2017-11-21"]
```

Is there any way to use php values instead?

Ideally, I would be able to put something like this in the editor itself

```
[radio date default:1 "1" "<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can make your own radio button shortcodes with different names you shoud go on this way. not to run php on editor.

you can use this hook

```
wpcf7_add_shortcode('date_radio_button', 'wpcf7_date_radio_button');
function wpcf7_date_radio_button($tag) {
    if (!is_array($tag)) return '';

    $name = $tag['name'];
    if (empty($name)) return '';

    $html = '<input type="radio" name="' . $name . '" value="' . date('Y-m-d') . '" />';
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: How do I properly use the shortcode for this it just shows up blank for me

Comment: [date_radio_button date_radio]

Comment: did you paste this into functions.php

Comment: No this is just a brief idea, that you can use like hooks and how will the function work. you have to put your logic into the function. if you want complete task form me then add me on skype rajkumar.gaur.91@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way to change the value of radio button,

What you need to do is, give an ID to radio button,

For example,

```
[radio field_name id:date_radio default:1 "1" "2" "3" "4"]
```

Where I have given ID "date_radio".

Now, in your page, you need to add following jQuery code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
        jQuery('#date_radio').find("input[type='radio']").attr('value','<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>'); // if you are going to put this code in .js file, then you need to get value from hidden field where you need to give date as value.
});
</script>
```

Make sure, Above code will change the value of all the radio option for given ID.

Please let me know if you need any further help in this.

Thanks!